# Optimisation jquery pour un affichage pdf

Tags: jquery, image, pdf

I'm on a Jquery project and I'm asked to optimize my code, except I don't see how to optimize it (shorter and quickly). Do you have any solutions to offer? Thanks a lot for your help.

```html
<span class="libellePrestation" onclick="setPDF(1);"></span>
function setPDF(id) {

var PDFName = "";

switch (id) {

case 1: PDFName = "01_buffet petit déjeuner.jpg"; break;
case 2: PDFName = "02_pause café seul.jpg"; break;
case 3: PDFName = "03_pause café avec boissons et biscuits.jpg"; break;
case 4: PDFName = "04_pause café avec boissons et gros biscuits.jpg"; break;
case 5: PDFName = "05_lunch baguettes garnies.jpg"; break;
case 6: PDFName = "06_lunch sandwichs garnis.jpg"; break;
case 7: PDFName = "07_lunch piccolo blanc et gris.jpg"; break;
case 8: PDFName = "08_lunch sandwichs prestige.jpg"; break;
case 9: PDFName = "09_lunch assiette froide.jpg"; break;
case 10: PDFName = "10_lunch assiette froide prestige.jpg"; break;
case 11: PDFName = "11_drink cocktail.jpg"; break;
case 12: PDFName = "12_cocktail dinatoire prestige.jpg"; break;
case 13: PDFName = "13_buffet froid.jpg"; break;
default: PDFName = "vide.png"; break;

}

if (id != 0) $("#pdfPreview").attr("src", "PDF/" + PDFName);

$("#pdfPreview").effect("slide", {}, 750, function () { });
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is the English only stack

Comment: "optimise" - in what way? Shorter code? Quicker code?  It won't run much quicker than the code you have, `switch` is already optimised.